# Control relay from Bluetooth on ATtiny85

Tags: arduino, power-supply, relay, bluetooth, attiny

I know someone else has made a Bluetooth transmitter to a relay so i wanted to ask a few questions about it being possible? I am an almost newbie at electronics but i do know a few things, so first of all I want to power my ATtiny85 from wall power because i want my ATtiny85 inside the wall of my house to control the roof light and i want it to be powered always how would i do that? Second is it possible to switch a 220V AC relay from the ATtiny85 if not would i be better off with an arduino?
Thanx

Comment: [one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25673/driving-a-relay-directly-with-a-microcontroller), [two](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59456/driving-a-relay-with-transistor-and-opto-isolator) and [three](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51522/how-can-i-drive-a-12v-automotive-relay-with-a-uc-running-on-5v).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know someone else has made a Bluetooth transmitter to a relay so i wanted to ask a few questions about it being possible?

Yes it is possible.

> I am an almost newbie at electronics but i do know a few things, so first of all I want to power my ATtiny85 from wall power because i want my ATtiny85 inside the wall of my house to control the roof light and i want it to be powered always how would i do that?

If you buy a module like HC-05, that needs two pins, TX (Transmit) and RX (Receive).

Example: http://arduinofy.blogspot.se/2013/05/attiny-bluetooth.html

> Second is it possible to switch a 220V AC relay from the ATtiny85

Yes, you need a driver since most 5volt relay needs more current than a ATtiny can handle.
A Relay driver is just a couple of discrete components.

Example:

[image]

Use the search words "arduino mosfet relay driver" at your favorite search engine and you will find what you are searching for.

> if not would i be better off with an arduino?

No, only if you need more memory and pins.

And as a addon: If you plan to control it from an Android I can recommend "App Inventor form MIT" to program your app or you can have a look at mine ;-)

Comment: Ohh, missed the power source.

I would have dissembled something like this http://goo.gl/9eGqUE as a 5volt power supply.

Comment: do I need a relay driver for this relay? http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/201151106679

Comment: No there is a relay driver included on the board.

http://imgs.inkfrog.com/pix/ebayimage2012/26074-7.jpg

Comment: Could you make a simple circuit diagram of how I set it up possibly? And do I need extra power for the relay and can I leave the bluetooth module plugged in 24/7?

Comment: `Could you make a simple circuit diagram of how I set it up possibly?`

When you ask it like that I would recommend that you start with a Arduino, a relay shield and a Bluetooth shield.

`And do I need extra power for the relay`

No

`and can I leave the bluetooth module plugged in 24/7`

Yes

Comment: Can't I just use the relay not a relay shield? The one from eBay. And do I need extra power for it?